# Struck on White Screen in emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I start the Android emulator only white blank screen is coming After that nothing is happening, Because of that, I changed the graphics settings to Software -GLES 2.0, Now the emulator is launching but it's very very slow, Taking more time to navigate from one screen to another.Please help me to resolve this

[Blank Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwMYn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue you have to go to the sidebar menu click **More>Settings>OpenGL ES Renderer and(in my case) set it to Angle(D3D11) or Angle(D3D9) or Swiftshader**. After that you have to restart the emulator.
Now Issue will be fixed!